# Find Duplicate in list but with criteria

Tags: c#, linq, list

Want to remove duplicates from a list so if my list contains:

```
www.test.com
test.com
mytest.com
```

I want the final list to look like below(only selecting the domains with www from the duplicate in front) :

```
www.test.com
mytest.com
```

I have this linq but it seems to ignore all the domains which dont have www in front because it is selecting only www ones:

```
var result=inputList.Where(x=>x.DomainName.StartsWith("www.")).Distinct();
```

**Edit:**

@DanielHilgarth: I just run your code and it doesnt produce right results. I have :

```
test.com 
www.test.com 
test2.com 
www.test2.com 
test3.com 
www.test3.com 
test4.com
```

in my list. It returns this :

```
test.com
www.test.com
www.test2.com 
www.test3.com
```

and here is how i use your code :

```
var result = lstServerBindings.GroupBy(x => x.DomainName.StartsWith("www.") ? x.DomainName : "www." + x)
                                                .Select(x =>
                                                {
                                                    var domain =
                                                        x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.DomainName.StartsWith("www."));
                                                    if (domain == null)
                                                        return x.First();
                                                    return domain;
                                                });
```

And then i do a foreach loop to assign to new list:

```
foreach (var item in result)
                            {
                                lstUniqueServerBindings.Add(new ServerBindings
                                {
                                    IPAddress = item.IPAddress,
                                    PortNumber = item.PortNumber,
                                    DomainName = item.DomainName
                                });

                            }
```

Comment: Just in case you don't mind solutions using IComparer && IEqualityComparer, please take a look at the one I finally posted (with some bug catching help from Daniel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to have something like this:

```
var result = domains.GroupBy(x => x.StartsWith("www.") ? x : "www." + x)
                    .Select(x =>
                            {
                                var domain =
                                    x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.StartsWith("www."));
                                if(domain == null)
                                    return x.First();
                                return domain;
                            });
```

I tested it with this input:

```
var domains = new List<string>
              {
                  "www.test.com",
                  "test.com",
                  "mytest.com",
                  "abc.com",
                  "www.abc.com"
              };
```

Result is:

```
www.test.com
mytest.com
www.abc.com
```

---

Your code should look like this (note the additional `.DomainName` at the end of the second line):

```
var result = lstServerBindings.GroupBy(x => x.DomainName.StartsWith("www.") ? 
                                            x.DomainName : "www." + x.DomainName)
                              .Select(x =>
                                      {
                                          var domain =
                                              x.FirstOrDefault(y => 
                                                y.DomainName.StartsWith("www."));
                                          if (domain == null)
                                              return x.First();
                                          return domain;
                                      });
```

BTW: You can save yourself the foreach loop by changing the code to this:

```
var result = lstServerBindings.GroupBy(x => x.DomainName.StartsWith("www.") ? 
                                            x.DomainName : "www." + x.DomainName)
                              .Select(x =>
                                      {
                                          var item =
                                              x.FirstOrDefault(y => 
                                                y.DomainName.StartsWith("www."));
                                          if (item == null)
                                              item = x.First();

                                          return new ServerBindings
                                              {
                                                  IPAddress = item.IPAddress,
                                                  PortNumber = item.PortNumber,
                                                  DomainName = item.DomainName
                                              };
                                      });
```

Comment: why not just `var result = domains.Select(x => x.StartsWith("www.") ? x : "www." + x).Distinct();` ?

Comment: Because it would return `www.mytest.com` instead of `mytest.com` as the second result.

Comment: what if you have a domain with no duplicate and no www in front? e.g."www.test.com",
                  "test.com",
                  "mytest.com",
                  "abc.com",
                  "www.abc.com","ddd.com"  would it return ddd.com as well

Comment: @Sam1: I am not sure I understand. "mytest.com" already is a domain without duplicate and without "www." in front and as you see, it is returned. But to answer your question: Yes, it would return "ddd.com" as well.

Comment: one more thing: you have named two different variables `result`. Perhaps you should try renaming one of them for the code to compile

Comment: @DanielHilgarth please see the edit above it doesnt return me the right values...

Comment: @Sam1: I think you are missing a `.DomainName` at the end of the first line. It should be: `var result = lstServerBindings.GroupBy(x => x.DomainName.StartsWith("www.") ? x.DomainName : "www." + x.DomainName)`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth oh thanks, I corrected that now im getting www.test.com, www.test2.com, test3.com, www.test3.com, test4.com... i should get www.test3.com...

Comment: @Sam1: Please check again. There must be an error somewhere in your code. Can you create a short working sample project that reproduces that problem?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I think i found the problem, if we have a space at the end it will not match right?

Comment: @Sam1: Correct. If that is a problem, change it to this: `x.DomainName.Trim() : "www." + x.DomainName.Trim()`

Answer (score 1):

This was a tricky one, but there's decently straightforward solution:

```
    public class wwwOrderComparison : IComparer<String>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if(x == null && y == null)
                return 0;
            if(x == null ^ y == null)
                return 0;

            var xWww = x.StartsWith("www");
            var yWww = y.StartsWith("www");

            return (xWww && x == "www." + y) ? -1 : ((yWww && "www." + x == y) ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    public class wwwEqualityComparison : IEqualityComparer<String>
    {
        public bool Equals(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
                return true;
            if (x == null ^ y == null)
                return false;

            var xWww = x.StartsWith("www");
            var yWww = y.StartsWith("www");
            if (xWww ^ yWww)
                return xWww ? (x == "www." + y) : ("www." + x == y);

            return xWww == yWww;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(string obj)
        {
            return (obj.StartsWith("www.") ? obj : ("www." + obj)).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Here's the test:

```
        var list = new List<String> {
            "www.test.com", 
            "test.com", 
            "mytest.com", 
            "abc.com", 
            "www.abc.com",
            "zzz.com",
            "www.zzz.com"
        };

        var s = list.OrderBy(t => t, new wwwOrderComparison()).Distinct(new wwwEqualityComparison()).ToList();
```

This has passed all my tests.  Cheers for the second time :)

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. It fails as soon as the URL starts with X, Y or Z. Try it by adding "www.zzz.com" and "zzz.com" to the list of domains.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth good point, let me see if I can touch it up...or not :P

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Sorry, I put that on the wrong post :p -- this updated one I think works...please let me know what you think!

Comment: It works. Still, I wouldn't use it, because of two reasons: It can be achieved with much less code (see my answer) and it re-orders the items.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - the code isn't what really bothers me (since it is consistent and easy to understand)...however the reordering is an annoying artifact

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - well, I've done it so that now it's all in place!  so now the extra code...how can I get rid of that and make ths work :-D (j/k)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Please see Daniel's response below. I was a bit too rushed on this one.

Use Select to do a projection of your elements, selecting/modifying certain properties. This might sound complex, but all you need to do is:

```
inputList.Select(x => x.Replace("www.", "")).Distinct()
```

Should work!

Edit: A little explanation. With select you can basically map your old objects into new ones, and then select these objects for your query. While in the case above you only select a simple string object, you could create a completely new object type with something like:

```
Select(x => new { Content = x, ContentLength = x.Length, ContentType = x.GetType() })
```

Here you construct a new object on the fly, based on your input objects' different properties and methods. Select is very useful and powerful!

Comment: **Bold** text doesn't work in code blocks ;) And the given solution doesn't really match the criteria, since the first result should be `www.test.com`.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about... ;)

Comment: but this would not give `www.test.com` though

Comment: @AndersHolmström: Please read the question again. This doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: Ouch, you are of course fully correct, Daniel. Yet another day of humbling SO experiences. :)

Comment: @Andres: you are replacing www in the linq above...If i do this I  will lose the one i want to select for example if my id for www.test.com is 1 and id for test.com is 2 by doing your linq i wouldn't know which domain had www in front...i hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

The normal .NET way to redefine what equality means (which is essentially what you are doing here) is to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

```
private class IgnoreWWWEqComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if(x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        if(x.StartsWith("www."))
        {
            if(y.StartsWith("www."))
                return x.Equals(y);
            return x.Substring(4).Equals(y);
            //the above line can be made faster, but this is a reasonable
            //approach if performance isn't critical
        }
        if(y.StartsWith("www."))
            return x.Equals(y.Substring(4));
        return x.Equals(y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
            return 0;
        if(obj.StartsWith("www."))
            return obj.Substring(4).GetHashCode();
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now `Distinct()` does what you want:

```
var result=inputList.OrderBy(s => !s.StartsWith("www.")).Distinct(new IgnoreWWWEqComparer());
```

For a one off, you might find it handier to just `group by` the string with any starting `www.` removed and select the first of each grouping, but the above should be quicker at throwing away the found duplicates, and of course `IgnoreWWWEqComparer` can be reused.

Edit:

Considering the requirement that "www." forms take precedence, then the above is fine, but it does slightly bug me to consider that it would be poor if we had a really large list to deal with. We'd want to make our `Equals` and `GetHashCode` better if we were being really bully about performance, but potentially sorting a massive list would be fine for a few dozen but begin to hurt after a while. Hence the following is not the approach I'd take if there would only be a small number (just go for the simpler), but would if it could be very large:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FavourWWWDistinct(IEnumerable<string> src)
{
  Dictionary<string, bool> dict = new Dictionary<string, bool>(new IgnoreWWWEqComparer());
  foreach(string str in src)
  {
    bool withWWW;
    if(dict.TryGetValue(str, out withWWW))
    {
      if(withWWW)
        continue;
      if(str.StartsWith("www."))
      {
        dict[str] = true;
        yield return str;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if(dict[str] = str.StartsWith("www."))
        yield return str;
    }
  }
  foreach(var kvp in dict)
    if(!kvp.Value)
      yield return kvp.Key;
}
```

This way we pass out those forms starting with `"www."` as soon as we see them, and only those which don't start with it have to wait for the whole list to be processed.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. It returns the domain without "www." as soon as it comes before the one with "www.". Example input: `new List<string>{ "www.test.com", "test.com", "mytest.com", "abc.com", "www.abc.com"};`. Your output: `"www.test.com", "mytest.com", "abc.com"`. Correct output would be: `"www.test.com", "mytest.com", "www.abc.com"`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth oops, I missed that as a requirement, just that it should be distinct on that basis. Have edited to fix.

Comment: @JonHanna: Yes, the new version works. Still, I wouldn't use it - see comment on Skyrim's answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth and another approach that's even better should the list of strings be very large.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth What, the re-ordering? Who cares?

Comment: @JonHanna: I don't know if he cares... :-) If the new list would be shown in the UI, I would care if it is in a completely different order than before.

Comment: Removing items inherently changes the order. Remove duplicates from A B C A D A E and whatever way you remove A some orderings have changed, whether "D is after an A" , "B is after and A" or "E is after an A". Order stability has to be not just requested in the case of removing duplicates, but actually specified as to just what is considered stable.

Comment: @JonHanna - You can use an IComparer with an OrderBy call to tweak it so that it preserves order.  Please reference my solution.