# Remove duplicates from list using criteria

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate filenames from a list that contains:

```
http://www.test.com/download/imagename_A.jpg
http://www.test.com/download/imagename_B.jpg
http://www.test.com/download/imagename_C.jpg
http://fc07.test.net/fs49/f/2009/216/6/f/imagename_A.jpg
http://fc09.test.net/fs49/f/2009/195/d/8/imagename_B.jpg
```

I want the final list to find duplicates that have the SAME filename, where if they do, the domain.net is selected over the domain.com, resulting in this final list:

```
http://fc07.test.net/fs49/f/2009/216/6/f/imagename_A.jpg
http://fc09.test.net/fs49/f/2009/195/d/8/imagename_B.jpg
http://www.test.com/download/imagename_C.jpg
```

I suspect that this can be done with linq (I found this article - [Find Duplicate in list but with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833344/find-duplicate-in-list-but-with-criteria)), but I don't know enough about linq to make it work for me.

Comment: `I don't know enough about linq to make it work for me`... I suggest you work through the article step by step with the focus of learning more about Linq, then try your own implementation.  If that doesn't work, post what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I think the issues I was running into were larger than I can figure out at this stage of my knowledge, but I plan on dissecting the answer, and learning from it.  I super appreciate this website and all the amazing people, who kindly help others get better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = urls.GroupBy(url => Path.GetFileName(url))
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(u=>new Uri(u).DnsSafeHost.EndsWith(".net")).First())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked, and gives me a great start to try to figure out how you did it.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.split('/') to split the URL (after converting URL to string) by "/" then compare the file names by checking the last position of the array that is created. Then you can split the second position of the array with string.split('.') and check for .net/.com in the third position of that array.